# Java DataInputStream DataOutputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to write in data already written by a person class into a `.dat` file using `java.io.DataInputStream`. Then, I want to output it using `java.io.DataOutputStream` through the console.

I know I just create the variables then use a scanner class, but what will the ultimate format be? Just need some headway.

Comment: DataOutputStream and DataInputStream are for binary data. You probably do not want to show them on the console. How exactly was the .dat file written? Can you show the code that did that?

Comment: I don't have any of then code written yet for the actual data input.

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is no such thing as a 'inputdatastream' in Java. The output format is entirely up to you and under your control: I don't know why you're asking about that here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could [serialize](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) the objects. The problem with default serialization is that the outcome is not well readable by humans and other applications. For that you would have to use something like [XML Marshalling](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/oxm.html) which produces something you can perhaps actually read.